# :first-child selector on cleared element

Tags: html, css

```css
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

ul::after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
}

ul:first-child {
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 2rem;
}

li {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>House</li>
    <li>Dog</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

With the Code above, find it weird that the :first-child selector (pseudo  class) is not working. I would have assumed that the li with `House` would have a red background. Instead there is no red background. Do you guys know why?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zQyVzM

Comment: you are selecting the ul not the li (add a space)

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the `first-child` pseudo class to the `li` tag, not the `ul`.

```css
li:first-child {
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 2rem;
}
```

As per the MDN [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) it selects the first element among it's siblings of the same element.